# Avoid dependency in nuget package

Tags: nuget

I have a class library a.dll which has dependency on "newtonsoft.json.dll" & b.dll (its a separate nuget package).

I am trying to create a nuget package for a.dll. For this package to work it needs b.dll.

When i refer the package for a.dll in a new project it adds a nuget reference to b.dll. I don't want that to happen. When i refer the a.dll package it should not force to install the nuget package b.dll.

Is there a way to avoid b.dll  from my package (a.dll). Please note that a.dll package needs b.dll to work.

Comment: In projects you can set `PrivateAssets` property as `None` for any PackageReference and it will not included in package. But this feature for `.NET Core` projects structure. Links: [IncludeAssets, ExcludeAssets and PrivateAssets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#includeassets-excludeassets-and-privateassets), [GitHub Issue #4125](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4125#issuecomment-267808514)

Comment: Hey if I do that will my package still works without those dependencies

Answer (score -1):

## Using 'old' style project file in combination with **package.nuspec** file

In order to pack a package without additional .dll that you rely on you will need to do two modifications.

Firstly, you will need to mark reference to **Newtonsoft.Json** as Copy Local False in Properties.

[image: Newtonsoft.Json dll set as Copy Local: False]

Secondly, you need to set **Newtonsoft.Json** as a dependency in a nuspec file.

```xml
<dependencies>
   <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.3" />
</dependencies>
```

This will allow Visual Studio to show and pull dependency packages from Nuget when user will install yours **a.nupkg** that will have **a.dll** and **b.dll** inside

## Using 'new' aka SDK style project file

This one is much easier as it does majority of work for you and all you need is have a PackageReference line in your project and `dotnet pack` command will know that this is an external dependency

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\b.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

For more information on both nuspec and project files PackageReference please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#Constraining_Upgrades_To_Allowed_Versions

Example of a full nuspec from Microsoft:
https://github.com/microsoft/CRA/blob/3ffff95fbbd89a682d17c7dc8a6930164598a440/src/CRA.Worker/CRA.nuspec

A more complex but still good example of ProjectReference example from non other than Newtonsoft.Json https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj